# Applying Admin Dashboard Template to Asp.NET MVC 5 Project

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-5, admin, dashboard

I am a intern guy and at company we work with Asp.NET MVC. Project manager give me some homework project to create a website some sort of music store. It's done but now  he gave me a theme, [Keenthemes Metronic](http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/) responsive admin dashboard template.

I searched all day but couldn't find anything about how can I apply them. Is there any step by step tutorial that would help me?

Comment: Isn't a theme just a collection of CSS stylesheets and HTML examples? To apply them, I would guess you copy the supplied CSS files into your project, and then load them as CSS assets. You can then follow the HTML examples to modify your existing project dashboard to use the theme's example HTML (which will use the theme's CSS).

Answer (score 0):

If you have that theme with you, u may add those to ur project with basics steps given in this link [Layout view in mvc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyQhEArGTNs) or else download or buy that theme and proceed with the steps shown in the tutorial.